Kiosk mode for android os using React Native App (locking device to specific app)
I have implemented react native app which we are using on android platform.
We need to implement kiosk mode(lock device to that app onle), means user will not able to close app, unable to access home screen of mobile/tablet.
Will appreciate your support. Please share any idea or links which help me to solve problem.
Thank you in advance
Kiosk Mode for android app using react native

we'll need more details like Device details (what device, version, name, etc.) React-Native version, etc.

Hello Thomasine, thanks for reply,
"react-native": "0.71.11",
Android 10 tablet (lenovo) 8" screen
